# what soap web service engine to use on jboss?

Tags: web-services, soap, jboss

I am developing a soap based middle-tier web service on jboss platform and would like to know, what engine or framework is the most matured or common for Enterprise level ?

So far i was considering:

1. Axis/Axis2
2. JbossWS

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Which version of JBoss, and which version of Java?

Comment: I haven't considered yet. could you advise on this ? i am not a java expert but have a deeper experience with other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend Apache CXF. Its a kind of meta service framework, also supporting SOAP.

I recommend lookup up some articles on the mainstream frameworks "Axis vs CXF" and select between the two based on your requirements.